# Place widget in center of QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

How can I place custom widget with fixed size in center of QScrollArea?

I can place the widget manually inside QScrollArea with myWidget.pos(x,y) but there is no sizeChanged signal in QScrollArea so this position will be wrong if scroll area changed.

Comment: What are your trying to do?

Comment: I think putting a widget in the center of scroll area neglects the meaning of the scrolling capabilities of the scroll area. Maybe you can consider using something else instead?

Comment: I use QScrollArea to display single widget, let's say a canvas for painting. And this canvas have scale capabilities, so it can be smaller then viewport or bigger, of course. So QScrollArea puts small child in top-left corner and it looks ugly.

Comment: @folibis You can use the [`alignment`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#alignment-prop) property to change the alignment of the scroll area's widget.

Comment: thank you @thuga, I really missed this property. Have to read the documenttion more intently

Comment: Don't forget to set a Maximum Height and Width to the widget otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I used @thuga's suggestion to set the alignment, but additionally I had to set a fixed size for the widget (I was settings only the minimum size before that), and also I needed to use a horizontal layout instead of a vertical one. For some reason, **the vertical layout disregards** the scroll area's horizontal alignment.

I used `setFixedSize()` to set a fixed size for my custom widget, but the layout and the alignment can be set from Qt Designer.