# How to center a widget in QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

Constructor:

```
ScrollArea::ScrollArea(...)
{
    ...
    end = myItems.count();
    for(int i=0; i<end; i++)
    {
        scrollItems.append(new ScrollItem(myItems.at(i), 0, width, i, this));
    }
    scrollArea->setWidget(this);    //must be last for auto-scrolling to work
}
```

Member function:

```
void ScrollArea::updateSelection(int selection)
{
    foreach(ScrollItem* item, scrollItems)
    {
        if(item->updateSelection(selection, 0))
        {
            scrollArea->ensureWidgetVisible(item);
        }
    }
}
```

After running `ScrollArea::updateSelection`, it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Google returns a mis-titled question (as far as I can tell: [Place widget in center of QScrollArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693764/place-widget-in-center-of-qscrollarea)) and a bunch of junk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know why `QScrollArea::ensureWidgetVisible` doesn't work, even with explicit margins, but I found something that does:

```
void ScrollArea::updateSelection(int selection)
{
    int item = -1;

    int i = scrollItems.count();
    while(i)
    {
        i--;
        if(scrollItems.at(i)->updateSelection(selection, 0))
        {
            item = i;
        }
    }

    if(item < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    i = scrollItems.first()->height();
    item *= i;
    item += i / 2;
    //item is now the position that should be centered

    scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(
                item - (scrollArea->height() / 2)
                );
}
```

So I'm basically brute-forcing what I want instead of having the library do it.  (and fail)

Comment: I am glad you worked that out with `verticalScrollBar()->setValue`.